# Нахождение максимального и минимального значения в массиве

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Найти минимальное и максимальное значение в массиве. Сохранить максимум и минимум в отдельной переменной.

Реализованный алгоритм:

```
    String gg = "-65649 -28979 -7098 60269 -20815 -13380 -78850 -7601 -62340 -1522 16584 57888 58337 58659 58809 29382 132 -56100 -14701 74564 11098 -79380 28418 -31457 50295 -44985 40248 -52332 25183 5280 71982 39533 56300 -15116 19802 -44514 51503 20952 27884 69163 -60570 -35531 47052 77766 -56872 25861 27149 23260 49761 -67551 17824 -19140 -66932 -33758 29402 63363 1257 -10350 -68969 -53559 74929 -76987 65973 51230 -12104 5776 -73284 -40600 -53272 34600 -51436 -33843 79068 75615 -36076 -57803 21476 71072 45456 -8762 -76479 -16719 52097 -63411 29523 1499 79951 -49220 71149 -69018 -22780 66078 -66005 -36806 37309 1891 48969 44025 41291 75697 -1374 69854 -38146 -2305 65469 5778 19891 6946 -3150 -14652 78183 371 48628 50281 16959 -1849 -28220 16910 28931 -37071 27892 -73848 -50992 41887 -30655 66317 -36222 -61685 30342 -74930 -65987 -51032 74923 -24134 26663 60392 61644 -33446 -12661 -21506 31901 -14478 58864 530 -44197 -4176 78680 7583 -67265 27612 50512 40627 33764 79520 2514 -76891 65837 46292 -58576 16180 51361 -44564 45148 46285 11302 -8189 26677 -7054 38365 -65983 51440 -9734 -462 30305 70795 35341 -53870 69476 -37075 -41136 17089 -66562 79490 -29147 -67042 2005 -26038 78795 -31702 -4615 14975 -60340 30821 -19876 65944 -37876 51934 12622 35070 10300 26638 6510 -79434 -53823 -43184 71361 61518 -17055 60838 -55557 21808 -2073 -42119 21299 48779 -29162 -56695 -57258 -30367 -8397 18127 64608 11262 -31052 -35267 -2793 11072 -63332 -70170 -33858 26967 36467 52652 27532 62644 -70532 18894 44162 -7588 -267 68605 -65779 77659 -53514 35519 46439 -2676 58824 69181 46957 -29573 7308 31566 61689 56256 76298 -21104 -12672 -67034 -11274 33470 39932 -54806 6122 -12536 -72162 15589 -73641 52000 -71998 6091 40606 -57778 3751 67092 57741 -29809 -15584 36566 -40628 -48626 -73007 46679 62939 68682 22935 59237 -32421 -69736 72202 36304 43733 32134 61497 -30145 -60401 69334 65444 -54042 41335";
    String[] mas = gg.split(" ");

    int[] mas_int = new int[mas.length];
    int counter = 0;

    for (String str : mas) {
        try {
            mas_int[counter] = Integer.parseInt(str);
        } catch (Exception error) {
            System.out.println("str = " + str);
        }
        counter++;
    }

    System.out.println("Колличество символов: " + mas_int.length);
    int max = mas_int[0], min = mas_int[1];

    for (int i = 0, j = 1; j < 300; i += 1, j += 1) {
        if (mas_int[i] >= mas_int[j]) {
            max = mas_int[i];
        }
        if (mas_int[i] < mas_int[j]) {
            min = mas_int[i];
        }
        if (mas_int[j] > mas_int[i]) {
            max = mas_int[j];
        }
        if (mas_int[j] < mas_int[i]) {
            min = mas_int[j];
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Максимум " + max + "\nМинимум " + min);
}
```

При выполнении кода выводит не правильные значения.

Comment: min при инициализации надо приравнивать тоже к нулевому элементу, а не к первому.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так - отсортировать и взять первое и последнее значение массива

```
Arrays.sort(arrInt);
int min = arrInt[0];
int max = arrInt[arrInt.length-1];
```

Comment: В полном описании написано, что лучше сделать вручную (типо обучение). И собственно в моем описании записано как нужно сделать, но все равно спасибо

Comment: Сортировка в лучшем случае - это алгоритм со сложность O(N * log N), а здесь достаточно выполнить только O(N), так что ваш ответ "не очень"

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в цикле:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mas_int.length; i++) {
    if (max <= mas_int[i]) {
        max = mas_int[i];
    }
    if (min >= mas_int[i]) {
        min = mas_int[i];
    }
```